# Model binding with two Search Results selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, model-binding

I have a MVC view which has contact information fields like firstName, lastName, Address, City, State and Zip. These fields get auto-populated from 2 search results drop-downs (lookupSLMRLeadRec() and lookupCRMLeadRec()). Also, I am using knockout for this MVC project.

Example: For Address1 population:

```
<div data-bind="visible: displayPhoneView">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>*Street<br />
                Address:</strong></td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vchAddress1, 
                new { data_bind = "value: lookupSLMRLeadRec().vchAddress", 
                @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: displayCRMView">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>*Street<br />
                Address:</strong></td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vchAddress1, 
                new { data_bind = "value: lookupCRMLeadRec().vchAddress", 
                @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Address1 is not getting passed into the model view, since the field gets populated based on two conditions.

Comment: What's `lookupSLMRLeadRec()` and `lookupCRMLeadRec()`? Show your Knockout view-model.

Comment: Help me understand your question you are saying lookupSLMRLeadRec() and lookupCRMLeadRec() are two drop-downs right? Now what do you want to do when you select value in drop-down you want to appear that in address1?